# Running vim in Console2 does not show colours properly

Tags: vim, colors, console2

So I am currently using [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for my command line stuff, the background shell is just the `cmd.exe` from windows. My problem is that I have the theme set to 'twilight` in vim, and it works perfectly in gVim, but when I run it through the command line, the colours are all messed up. They remain broken even if I use the default Console2 theme or even the twilight theme for Console2.

For illustration: This is what should happen:
[image]

But these are the colours I end up getting instead:
[image]

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows shell (and with it, the *Console2* wrapper) is limited to **16 colors**, whereas GVIM can use the full 24-bit RGB palette. Therefore, even with colorscheme support for consoles, there usually are limitations.

The best you can achieve is adapt the shell's / Console2's color palette to the (maximum 16) RGB colors used by the *twilight* color scheme, and then adapt the `ctermfg=` and `ctermbg=` entries in the colorscheme to the corresponding indices.

#### Steps

In the `colors/twilight.vim`, you'll find the following definitions:

```
let s:grey_blue = '#8a9597'
let s:light_grey_blue = '#a0a8b0'
let s:dark_grey_blue = '#34383c'
let s:mid_grey_blue = '#64686c'
let s:beige = '#ceb67f'
let s:light_orange = '#ebc471'
let s:yellow = '#e3d796'
let s:violet = '#a999ac'
let s:green = '#a2a96f'
let s:lightgreen = '#c2c98f'
let s:red = '#d08356'
let s:cyan = '#74dad9'
let s:darkgrey = '#1a1a1a'
let s:grey = '#303030'
let s:lightgrey = '#605958'
let s:white = '#fffedc'
```

You need to redefine your Console2 colors in the *color map* to those (best trying to match similar existing colors, or other program output will look weird).

[image: Console color settings]

Then, modify the `colors/twilight.vim` script, adding the color terminal stuff, e.g. turn this

```
exe 'hi String         guifg='.s:green             .' guibg='.s:darkgrey        .' gui=none'
```

into (assuming you've used color #0 for `s:darkgrey` and #10 for `s:green`)

```
exe 'hi String         ctermfg=10 ctermbg=0 guifg='.s:green             .' guibg='.s:darkgrey        .' gui=none'
```

Comment: Could you explain how I could do this? I'm a bit confused on how to accomplish it.

Comment: @Link: I've added the steps; note that I've never explicitly done this, but I'm convinced it should work.