# Console2 Color Scheme

Tags: console2, git-bash

I'm using console2 with git bash and powershell. I've set the colorscheme to monokai, but the console does not use the configured colors. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to have console2 use the color scheme?

Comment: Where exactly did you setup "monokai" why do you think, configured colors are not used? Have you created new tab? Anyway... you may try ConEmu too.

Comment: I setup "monokai" in the console.xml file. I believe the colors are not used because whether in git bash or powershell vim colors do not match the monokai setup.

Comment: [the Console2 wrapper is limited to 16 colors](http://superuser.com/a/668728/57579), can that be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how you set up the colors I am limited in what I can say, but I can give you instructions for how I did it.

The [Console2 monokai on Github](https://github.com/tstone/console2-monokai) has a file with all the colors defined using the Monokai color scheme. You can copy the `colors` portion of his `console.xml` to overwrite the `colors` portion of your `console.xml` file.

**When editing the `console.xml` file, make sure that the Console 2 window is closed first.** If you have the Console 2 window open while you edit the `console.xml` file, you will not see your changes inside Console 2, and when you restart Console 2, it will overwrite your changes with the configuration that it used when it was opened last. So, close Console 2, edit and save `console.xml`, and then open Console 2.